# Gathering an array of different sizes on various processes into one array with MPI and mpi4py in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mpi, hpc

I have matrix's on a bunch of different processes but they are all not necessarily the same size so I don't think I can use comm.gather() or equivalents. Therefore, I have written my own function but I get really weird error at line with:

```
self.test_array_global[list_count:list_count+ count_symbol_list[count+1]] = temp_ar
```

It seems this line doesn't access the self.test_array_global indexing correctly for some reason that I can't figure out because I get this error. Even if I manually try to set the shape of self.test_array_global above it still seems not to work..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AudModMPI.py", line 183, in <module>
    aud.get_test_array()
  File "AudModMPI.py", line 149, in get_test_array
    self.test_array_global[list_count:list_count+ count_symbol_list[count+1]] = temp_ar
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (82,300,50) into shape (0,300,50)
```

Here is the whole function:

```
def get_test_array(self, to_rank=0):
    if rank != to_rank:
                comm.send(self.test_symbol_list, dest=to_rank, tag=20)
    if (rank == to_rank):
        itera = range(num_proc)
        itera.remove(to_rank)
        self.test_symbol_list_global = []
        self.test_symbol_list_global.extend(self.test_symbol_list)
        count_symbol_list = [len(self.test_symbol_list)]
        temp_list = None
        for i in itera:
            temp_list = comm.recv(source=i, tag=20)
            count_symbol_list.append(len(temp_list))
            self.test_symbol_list_global.extend(temp_list)

    if rank != to_rank:
        comm.Send(self.test_array[0:len(self.test_symbol_list)], dest=to_rank, tag=21)
    if rank == to_rank and num_proc > 1:
        self.test_array_global = zeros((count_symbol_list[-1], self.test_array.shape[1], self.test_array.shape[2]))
        list_count = 0
        for count, i in enumerate(itera):
            list_count += count_symbol_list[count]
            temp_ar = empty((count_symbol_list[count+1], self.test_array.shape[1], self.test_array.shape[2]))
            comm.Recv(temp_ar, source=i, tag=21)
            print rank, list_count
            print rank, count_symbol_list[count+1]
            self.test_array_global[list_count:list_count+ count_symbol_list[count+1]] = temp_ar

        self.test_array_global[0:len(self.test_symbol_list)] = self.test_array[0:len(self.test_symbol_list)]
```

Comment: "... they are all not necessarily the same size so I don't think I can use comm.gather() or equivalents". Which equivalents? `MPI_Gatherv` (or whatever its equivalent in mpi4py) allows you to gather pieces of varying sizes from each rank.